# how to find span html if we click on image?

Tags: jquery

How to get  `Descriptions` name if we click on `<img src="../Images/Checkmark.ico"`

```
<li id="liRightDescriptions" style="display: list-item;">
         <span><span>Descriptions</span>
        <img src="../Images/Checkmark.ico" class="checkImage"></span>
    </li>
```

i tired this :-

```
$('.checkImage').live('click', function (event) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).prev().html();
```

Comment: DOM is a tree. Every node in the tree knows where it is, what its parent node is, and what child/sibling nodes it has. So: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: you're opening two `<span>` after another

Comment: $(this).siblings().text()

Comment: @simplyray, you neglected to see he closed both spans

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.checkImage').click( function () {
    var name = $(this).prev().html();
    alert(name)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `live` its depreciated

```
$('body').delegate('.checkImage','click',function(){
alert($(this).prev().html());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use the `.siblings()` selector ( http://api.jquery.com/siblings/ )

as an example :

```
$('.checkImage').live('click', function (event) {
  var name = $('.checkImage.').siblings('span').html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `live()` function is deprecated and has been replaced with `on()`, use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.checkImage', function(){
    var text = $(this).prev('span').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.checkImage').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).prev().html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That would likely work, except you have no closing **/** in your image, and perhaps more.
By the way... using .click() is slower than using .on() ...and .live() is depreciated.

I got it working, so here's a fixed fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/QT66f/

Basically the same, but I removed things you may not actually need. Re-add them if you do.

```
$('.checkImage').on('click', function (event) {
        var name = $(this).prev().html();
        alert( name )
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<li id="liRightDescriptions" style="display: list-item;">
    <span>
        <span>Descriptions</span>
        <img src="../Images/Checkmark.ico" class="checkImage" />
    </span>
</li>
```